# Protractor is not waiting for page to load though the element is present

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

1. I am trying to enter otp in the text box by using sendkeys but it is not working. I have also tried by using browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true)but no luck.

> ```
>   element(by.css(".inputOtp > input")).sendKeys('909090');
> ```

2. By using executescript it is entering text in the textbox.

   ```
   browser.executeScript("document.querySelector(\".inputOtp > input\").value='909090'");
   ```
3. Now the problem is it is not click on  continue button which is present on the same page.

> `element(by.id('otp-verify-and-continue')).click()`

[image]

Comment: You may need to create and send a mouse event instead. If you open the in firefox's inspector. You can see what events are bound to that button element.

Answer (score 1):

We wrote it in our project:

```
// Ensure element is loaded in DOM
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element.all(by.className(elementToFind)).first()), 60000);
expect(element.all(by.className(elementToFind)).first().isPresent()).toBe(true, 'the element is not presented at the page after Timeout');
// Find it
el = element.all(by.className(elementToFind)).first();
// Ensure it is displayed and do things
el.isDisplayed();
el.sendKeys(keysToSend);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best option to wait for the button presence is `browser.wait()`. You should use it before clicking the *verify and Continue* Button. (**Do wait and check for visibility instead of Presence**) as
`browser.wait(protactorObject.visibilityOf(element(by.id('otp-verify-and-continue'))),60000)`